# MYSQL DateTime - PHP Conversion

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL datetime that looks like this - 2011-08-28 12:39:21

I need (in PHP) to see if the time is within 3 minutes of the current time.
I know how to do it in MySQL like 'BETWEEN NOW()-INTERVAL 3 MINUTE AND NOW()',
But in this case I need to do it in PHP.

Advice on how to findout if the datetime is within the last 3 minutes or now?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
if (strtotime($datetime) >= time() - 180) {
    // within last three minutes or later
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

```
if (strtotime($datetime) >= time() - 180) {
    // within last three minutes or later
}
```

if you dont upgrade from your server MYSQL 5.2 and plus your dont fixed this.